# JSpinner with custom UI

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I am developing swing-base application with custom design. One of the task - customize spinner control. I want to achieve something like this : 
[image: design spinner] 
 
My main problem is that spinner controls overlap it's border : 
[image: resulted spinner] 
Code that creates spinner:

```
public class GolfSpinner extends JSpinner {

    public GolfSpinner() {
        setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(Colors.INPUT_BORDER.getR()
                , Colors.INPUT_BORDER.getG(), Colors.INPUT_BORDER.getB()), 1, true));
        setEditor(new Editor(this));
        setUI(new GolfSpinnerUI());
    }

    private class GolfSpinnerUI extends BasicSpinnerUI {

        @Override
        protected Component createPreviousButton() {
            Component component = createButton(Icons.ARROW_DOWN.getUrl());
            super.createPreviousButton();
            if (component != null) {
                installPreviousButtonListeners(component);
            }
            return component;
        }

        @Override
        protected Component createNextButton() {
            Component component = createButton(Icons.ARROW_UP.getUrl());
            if (component != null) {
                installNextButtonListeners(component);
            }
            return component;
        }

        private Component createButton(String url) {
            BufferedImage icon = null;
            try {
                icon = ImageIO.read(new File(url));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            if (icon != null) {
                JButton arrowButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(icon));
                arrowButton.setBackground(new Color(Colors.APP_PANEL_BACKGROUND.getR()
                        , Colors.APP_PANEL_BACKGROUND.getG(), Colors.APP_PANEL_BACKGROUND.getB()));
                arrowButton.setBorderPainted(false);
                arrowButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(icon.getWidth() + 15, icon.getHeight() + 5));
                return arrowButton;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

    private class Editor extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {

        private JLabel label = new JLabel();

        private Editor(JSpinner spinner) {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
            label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 6, 5, 0));
            add(label);
            spinner.addChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSpinner spinner = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
            label.setText(spinner.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to change prefered size of spinner but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at how these PLAFs do it.

[image: Motif PLAF]  [image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

class SwingSpinnerLook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(
                        new SpinnerNumberModel(10,1,100,1));
                gui.add(spinner, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

                final UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] plafInfos =
                    UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
                String[] plafNames = new String[plafInfos.length];
                for (int ii=0; ii<plafInfos.length; ii++) {
                    plafNames[ii] = plafInfos[ii].getName();
                }
                final JComboBox<String> plafChooser = new JComboBox<String>(plafNames);
                gui.add(plafChooser);
                ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int index = plafChooser.getSelectedIndex();
                        try {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                                plafInfos[index].getClassName() );
                            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(gui);
                        } catch(Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                plafChooser.addActionListener(al);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you advice! I'll check it and if achive desire design -  post code. For now i found temporary solution by using **MatteBorder** on arrow buttons. It's not perfect but better than nothing.